# restore a hidden trash folder

Tags: nautilus, trash

I have Ubuntu installed in one drive and another drive for data.
Using Nautilus I deleted a hidden folder in the data drive.
That hidden folder moved to Trash and will no longer restore.
I cannot empty Trash either.
Also, Trash will only first show its contents when the data drive is mounted.

How can I restore the hidden folder to the data drive?, how can I restore Trash behaviour for this drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can try retrieving this hidden folder with the Terminal.
A lot of people aren't aware that the Trash folder is actually located in their home folder.But we know,so we simply navigate there using `cd`:

```
cd ~/.local/share/Trash/files
```

Now we list the content of this directory with `ls -la`
You should now be able to see the contents of your Trash folder,including your lost hidden folder.With the next line, we copy this folder to `~/Save`

```
cp .<hiddenfolder_name> ~/Save/
```

Note that "~" is like a shortcut to your home directory,it's in fact the same as `/home/<user>/`

Now on the problem that the Trash folder only shows up when your data drive is mounted:
I suspect that the data drive contains your `/home/` folder, and seeing as the Trash folder is located in your home, it is not visible until your home folder is mounted.
The location of the Trash folder may vary on the huge variety of distros,you may have to look it up for your distro in case the one I named doesn't work for you.From the question itself I can't really tell wether your home folder is on the data drive, so if this isn't the case it would propably help to solve your problem if you could provide this info.    I hope this helps you retriveing your hidden folder...May the force be with you!